# Is there a way to css grid this specific layout in one grid container and possibly infinite rows (with 3 items)?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a one div which is "display:grid".

```
<div>
  <article>article1</article>
  <article>article2</article>
  <article>article3</article>
  <article>article4</article>
  <article>article5</article>
  <article>article6</article>
  ...
</div>
```

I want to have this specific layout :
[image]

I manage to have it working using a 6 grid-template-columns but my concern is that when there is more than 10 articles for example, the 11th article will be 1/6 wide as the grid is only 5 grid-template-rows :

[image]

How would it be possible to achieve that layout (infinite 3 articles in a row) if there was tens of articles, and so, not knowing the number of rows needed, and keeping the original structure (one grid div with articles children) ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to do this by using a grid that's 6 columns wide then using grid-column to get the children to fit the grid child elements in the right place. To select which grid items fit which element then use `nth-child` to pick the right ones as below:

- nth-child on [css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/)
- [grid-column](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column) and [grid-row](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-row) on MDN

**Edited to add**: I've noticed at small screen widths that the `1fr` unit does not scale the columns evenly so I've fixed this by changing `grid-template-columns` from `repeat(6, 1fr)` to `repeat(6, minmax(0,1fr))`.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, minmax(0, 1fr));
}

.container > article {
  background-color: #8C78FE;
  padding: 1rem 1rem;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1rem;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}

article:first-child {
  grid-column: 1/span 3;
  grid-row: 1/span 3;
}

article:nth-child(-n + 4):not(:first-child) {
  grid-column: 4/span 3;
}

article:nth-child(n+5) {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

article:nth-child(n+11) {
  grid-column: span 1;
  background-color: #C6BBFF;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <article>article1</article>
  <article>article2</article>
  <article>article3</article>
  <article>article4</article>
  <article>article5</article>
  <article>article6</article>
  <article>article7</article>
  <article>article8</article>
  <article>article9</article>
  <article>article10</article>
  <article>article11</article>
  <article>article12</article>
  <article>article13</article>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Adam. You just made me discover the grid-column:span property. This is exactly what i needed. Thanks for your precious help.

Comment: FYI I've just amended my answer slightly to change grid-template-columns from repeat(6, 1fr) to repeat(6, minmax(0, 1fr)).

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for the follow-up, i was really stuck in the grid learning process with this one. Seems so easy when you explained it.